# Abstracting over Collection Types

Tags: collections, f#, language-features

Is there a possibility of writing functions which are generic in respect to collection types they support other than using the `seq` module?

The goal is, not having to resort to copy and paste when adding new collection functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `seq<'T>` type is the primary way of writing computations that work for any collections in F#. There are a few ways you can work with the type:

- You can use functions from the `Seq` module (such as `Seq.filter`, `Seq.windowed` etc.)
- You can use sequence comprehensions (e.g. `seq { for x in col -> x * 2 }`)
- You can use the underlying (imperative) `IEnumerator<'T>` type, which is sometimes needed e.g. if you want to implement your own zipping of collections (this is returned by calling `GetEnumerator`)

This is relatively simple type and it can be used only for reading data from collections. As the result, you'll always get a value of type `seq<'T>` which is essentially a lazy sequence.

F# doesn't have any mechanism for transforming collections (e.g. generic function taking collection `C` to collection `C` with new values) or any mechanism for creating collections (which is available in Haskell or Scala).

In most of the practical cases, I don't find that a problem - most of the work can be done using `seq<'T>` and when you need a specialized collection (e.g. array for performance), you typically need a slightly different implementation anyway.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. So if I want to keep the information about the type of my original collection (say to avoid later being forced to call `Seq.toArray` when wanting to chain a "Knuth shuffle" to a hand rolled zipWith operation beforehand) I have to bite the bullet and copy and paste zipWith for all collection types I want to support?

Comment: @Alexander: Yes, writing completely container-independent algorithms (like in C++ for example) is not possible in F#, as far as I'm aware. I guess one could theoretically implement object-oriented wrappers around the different collections types...but would that be worth it? - Wrt. to `zipWith`: All collection modules support a `map2` function.

Comment: @wmeyer: Thanks. Being able to write algorithms  independent from the container implementation is a valuable feature for me. As I was told that in most practical cases lack of this ability is not a problem, I assume that I do not understand in a fundamental way how to structure F# code.

Comment: I would guess that if you mostly write algorithms that take a `seq` as input and return an `array` as output, you'd be in good shape for most cases with very little massaging... But I could be wrong.

Comment: @Brian: Thanks, I will try that and see how it looks and performs in my case(s).

Answer (score 2):

Generic programming with collections can be handled the same way generic programming is done in general: Using generics.

```
let f (map_fun : ('T1 -> 'T2) -> 'T1s -> 'T2s) (iter_fun : ('T2 -> unit) -> 'T2s -> unit) (ts : 'T1s) (g : 'T1 -> 'T2) (h : 'T2 -> unit)=
    ts
    |> map_fun g
    |> iter_fun h

type A =
    static member F(ts, g, h) = f (Array.map) (Array.iter) ts g h
    static member F(ts, g, h) = f (List.map) (List.iter) ts g h
```

A bit ugly and verbose, but it's possible. I'm using a class and static members to take advantage of overloading. In your code, you can just use A.F and the correct specialization will be called.

For a prettier solution, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/979084/what-features-would-you-add-remove-or-change-in-f/987569#987569 Although this feature is enabled only for the core library, it should not be a problem to modify the compiler to allow it in your code. That's possible because the source code of the compiler is open.

Comment: Thanks, Joh. This is indeed quite verbose.