# Ruby Hash value traversal and changing value is not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

```
a = {"a" => 100, "b" => 200, "c" => 300}

b = a.map{|k,v| v = v + 10}
```

is returning an array, i need to change the values of a hash by call by reference

I am expecting the following output

```
{"a" => 110, "b" => 210, "c" => 310}
```

Thanks

Comment: unless perfomance is an issue, consider non-destructive functional solutions (each -> map). I think what you need here is a fmap for Hash (though useful, functors is a FP concept hardly seen in Ruby).

Comment: @tokland: What's a fmap?

Comment: @Andrew: fmap is a generalization of map for functors (something we can iterate over). It's commonly seen in Haskell, check for example http://learnyouahaskell.com/functors-applicative-functors-and-monoids. For Ruby, check this example: http://code.google.com/p/tokland/wiki/RubyAlgebraicDataTypes, I wrote a Tree#fmap in adt_tree.rb. Also, check my comment in d11wtq's answer.

Comment: @tokland: Nice. You may want to talk about fmap as an answer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5738065/is-rubys-returning-of-a-different-type-after-a-filter-unusual-from-a-functional , though Ed'ka has made a comment mentioning fmap.

Comment: @Andrew, done, I added an answer with my 2-cents.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Maybe you can do something like this:

```
a.keys.each do |key| a[key] += 10 end
```

Comment: yeah, this is better than mine (+1)

Comment: @jaydel: actually yours is "better" because a.keys builds an intermediate array.

Comment: @tokland also this solution is touching original hash

Comment: @fl00r: yeah, I know. But I mean, if you are going the ugly imperative way, it's better to use Array#each_key. Personally I would create a new hash without hesitation (unless "a" is humongous). (edit) Now that I check the question, the OP wants a new "b", so d11wtq's is definitely the way to go.

Answer (score 8):

Here's my non-mutating one-liner :P

```
Hash[original_hash.map { |k,v| [k, v+10] }]
```

Gotta love ruby one-liners :)

Comment: +1 for the functional solution. You can generalize it as a fmap: class Hash
  def fmap(&block)
    Hash[self.map(&block)]
  end
end

x = {:a => 1, :b => 2}.fmap { |k, v| [k.to_s, v*2] }
p x #{"a"=>2, "b"=>4}

Answer (score 4):

```
a.each_pair do |x,y| a[x] += 10 end
```

Comment: With this approach use Hash#each_key.

Answer (score 4):

Reality check:

```
require "benchmark"
include Benchmark

h0, h1, h2, h3, h4 = (0..4).map { Hash[(0..1000).map{ |i| [i,i] }] }

bm do |x|
  x.report("0") { 1000.times { h0.each_key{ |k| h0[k] += 10 } } }
  x.report("1") { 1000.times { h1.keys.each{ |k| h1[k] += 10 } } }
  x.report("2") { 1000.times { Hash[h2.map { |k,v| [k, v+10] }] } }
  x.report("3") { 1000.times { h3.inject({}){ |h,(k,v)| h[k] = v + 10; h } } }
  x.report("4") { 1000.times { h4.inject({}){ |h,(k,v)| h.update( k => v + 10) } } }
end

      user     system      total        real
0  0.490000   0.000000   0.490000 (  0.540795)
1  0.490000   0.010000   0.500000 (  0.545050)
2  1.210000   0.010000   1.220000 (  1.388739)
3  1.570000   0.010000   1.580000 (  1.660317)
4  2.460000   0.010000   2.470000 (  3.057287)
```

Imperative programming wins.

Comment: +1 for doing some research (but which implementation did you run it on?), but if you're modifying an object that you didn't create (eg it's a method parameter) then you may wish to avoid the imperative approach.

Comment: @Andrew Grimm Ruby Enterprise 1.8.7, I prefer functional approach, but good looking code is too often slower, so I made a habit of doing benchmarks every time.

Answer (score 1):

Dude change the `map` with `each` and you are good to go :)

Answer (score 1):

I believe in every Ruby question `inject` should be presented :D

```
b = a.inject({}){ |h,(k,v)| h[k] = v + 10; h }
#=> {"a"=>110, "b"=>210, "c"=>310}
```

Comment: Inject is cool, but sometimes its usage shadows a more specific functional construction (because "everything" can be written as a fold...). Here a hash creation (Hash[pairs]) seems more natural (the hoped-for Enumerable#mash would be even better). Notice that it can be written: a.inject({}){ |h,(k,v)| h.update(k => v + 10) }

Comment: Wouldn't `each_with_object` be more applicable here?

Comment: @Andrew: indeed. Though personally I don't like each_with_object because it encourages in-place modifications (with inject you're free to do it or not)

Comment: Just as a curiosity, I found this answer from Jörg (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3833372/functional-code-examples-in-ruby/3834035#3834035) where uses folding/reduce/inject to implement every method in Enumerable.